# Optimizar funciones en Javasript

Tags: javascript, funciones, revisión-de-código

Quería saber si se podía optimizar la función esta para no usar tantos if consecutivos y poder usar uno solo, pero no puedo dar con la tecla en los parámetros.
Mi Javascript es este:

```
const productoSelected = (producto) => {
    if (producto==""){
        alert("No se ha ingresado nada");
    }
    return producto;
}
const comprobacion = (seleccion) => {
    if ((seleccion === "Manijas") || (seleccion === "manijas")) {
        let presupuesto = parseInt(prompt("Seleccione su presupuesto para las " + seleccion));
        while (presupuesto <= 1500) {
            alert("Su presupuesto es muy chico, por favor, ingrese una nueva cantidad de dinero superior a $1.500");
            presupuesto = parseInt(prompt("Seleccione su presupuesto para las " + seleccion))
        }
        alert ("Su presupuesto es correcto")
    }
    if ((seleccion === "Cerraduras") || (seleccion === "cerraduras")) {
        let presupuesto = parseInt(prompt("Seleccione su presupuesto para las " + seleccion));
        while (presupuesto <= 1500) {
            alert("Su presupuesto es muy chico, por favor, ingrese una nueva cantidad de dinero superior a $1.500");
            presupuesto = parseInt(prompt("Seleccione su presupuesto para las " + seleccion))
        }
        alert ("Su presupuesto es correcto")
    }
    if ((seleccion === "máquinas") || (seleccion === "maquinas") || (seleccion === "Máquinas") || (seleccion === "Maquinas")) {
        let presupuesto = parseInt(prompt("Seleccione su presupuesto para las " + seleccion));
        while (presupuesto <= 1500) {
            alert("Su presupuesto es muy chico, por favor, ingrese una nueva cantidad de dinero superior a $1.500");
            presupuesto = parseInt(prompt("Seleccione su presupuesto para las " + seleccion))
        }
        alert ("Su presupuesto es correcto")
    }
}

comprobacion(productoSelected(prompt("Escriba los productos. Los productos son los siguientes \n1. Manijas \n2. Máquinas\n3.Cerraduras")));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vamos a refactorizar ese código por iteraciones, paso a paso:

- Como norma general, si ves líneas de código muy similares o idénticas, esa parte se puede simplificar. Por ejemplo, tu código tiene varias veces

```javascript
let presupuesto = parseInt(prompt("Seleccione su presupuesto para las " + seleccion));
  while (presupuesto <= 1500) {
    alert("Su presupuesto es muy chico, por favor, ingrese una nueva cantidad de dinero superior a $1.500");
    presupuesto = parseInt(prompt("Seleccione su presupuesto para las " + seleccion))
  }
alert ("Su presupuesto es correcto")
```

Por tanto podrías crear una función que recogiera ese código:

```javascript
const comprobacion = (seleccion) => {
  if ((seleccion === "Manijas") || (seleccion === "manijas")) {
    pedirPresupuesto(seleccion)
  }
  if ((seleccion === "Cerraduras") || (seleccion === "cerraduras")) {
    pedirPresupuesto(seleccion)
  }
  if ((seleccion === "máquinas") || (seleccion === "maquinas") || (seleccion === "Máquinas") || (seleccion === "Maquinas")) {
    pedirPresupuesto(seleccion)
  }
}

function pedirPresupuesto(seleccion) {
  let presupuesto = parseInt(prompt("Seleccione su presupuesto para las " + seleccion));
  while (presupuesto <= 1500) {
    alert("Su presupuesto es muy chico, por favor, ingrese una nueva cantidad de dinero superior a $1.500");
    presupuesto = parseInt(prompt("Seleccione su presupuesto para las " + seleccion))
  }
  alert("Su presupuesto es correcto")
}
```

- Ahora las funciones son más sencillas y podemos ver mejor qué intentas hacer. De nuevo nos podemos dar cuenta de que hay repeticiones que se podrían resumir en: si la selección es válida, entonces se llama a la función que acabamos de crear. Refactoricemos de nuevo, eliminando las repeticiones y creando otra función auxiliar:

```javascript
const comprobacion = (seleccion) => {
  let presupuesto;
  if (esSeleccionValida(seleccion)) {
    presupuesto = pedirPresupuesto(seleccion)
  }
  console.log("El presupuesto es de ", presupuesto);
}

function pedirPresupuesto(seleccion) {
  let presupuesto = parseInt(prompt("Seleccione su presupuesto para las " + seleccion));
  while (presupuesto <= 1500) {
    alert("Su presupuesto es muy chico, por favor, ingrese una nueva cantidad de dinero superior a $1.500");
    presupuesto = parseInt(prompt("Seleccione su presupuesto para las " + seleccion))
  }
  alert("Su presupuesto es correcto")
  return presupuesto;
}

const PRODUCTOS = [ "manijas", "cerraduras", "maquinas"]
function esSeleccionValida(seleccion) {
  const seleccionSinAcentosEnMinusculas = seleccion.toLowercase()
    .replace(/á/g,"a")
    .replace(/é/g,"e")
    .replace(/í/g,"i")
    .replace(/ó/g,"o")
    .replace(/ú/g,"u");
  return PRODUCTOS.includes(seleccionSinAcentosEnMinusculas);
  
}
```

Esto nos deja un código legible a varios niveles:

- Si sólo quieres saber **qué** se ha implementado, leyendo la función `comprobacion` tienes una descripción a alto nivel de todo el código.
- Tenemos dos funciones auxiliares que nos muestran **cómo** se ha implementado la funcionalidad

Además nos da flexibilidad:

- Añadir un nuevo producto ahora no implica más que añadirlo al array de productos, la lógica no ha de tocarse.
- El límite del presupuesto ahora está definido una vez, con lo que un cambio sólo se ha de realizar en un sitio.

Comment: Muchas Gracias Pablo! Súper funciona! Saludos!!